# Using Redux, Typescript Typing in different folder to the JS module. How to tell it where the module lives?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, typescript-typings

I'm using Redux in my application.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and npm to download Redux as a dependency.

I have the following folder structure:

```
MySolution.sln
├── node_modules
│   ├── redux
│   │   ├── index.d.ts
|   |   ├── dist
│   │   |   ├── redux.js
│   │   |   ├── redux.min.js
├── Scripts
│   ├── myscript.ts
│   ├── myscript.js
```

The node structure for Redux is as it comes when downloaded using npm

> npm install redux

I have a TypeScript script (myscript.ts), that makes use of Redux, I import `createStore` and `combineReducers` from it.

**myscript.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/redux/index.d.ts" />
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "../node_modules/redux/index";

//... more code
const myApp = combineReducers({
    SelectedAnswers: selectedAnswers
});

var store = createStore(myApp);
```

Which compiles to the following (**myscript.js**):

```
define(["require", "exports", "../node_modules/redux/index"], function (require, exports, index_1) {
    "use strict";
    var _this = this;
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

    var questionApp = index_1.combineReducers({
        SelectedAnswers: selectedAnswers
    });

    var store = index_1.createStore(questionApp);
});
```

As you can see, my code uses an import script, this was generated by Visual Studio/TypeScript automatically.

This is fine for compilation purposes, because it points to `../../../node_modules/redux/index` which will allow it to pick up `index.d.ts` which is the TypeScript typings file (Definitely Typed).

So my problem comes when the application actually runs, the real script for Redux is in the next folder up, `/redux.js`, so when I run my script it tells me that the module isn't able to load.

How do I tell TypeScript that the script lives in `/redux` at run time?

I thought that if I specified it in the `require.config` against the name htat appears in the TypeScript generated `define()` method, that I could tell RequireJS where the script is, but this didn't have any effect:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        "../node_modules/redux/index": "../node_modules/redux/dist/redux"
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help.

NB: It works fine if I move `index.d.ts` into the same folder as `redux.js` and call it `redux.d.ts`, but this isn't how it appears in the npm download.  I don't want to have to move them into the same folder every time I update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the main source of my pain is that I was mixing up the concepts of internal modules and external modules.

External modules aren't generally referenced by their relative paths within the tapestry of TypeScript files that make up an application, these should be specified within the `require.config()`.

Internal modules and TypeScript files can be referenced with relative paths.

So the answer is that `redux`, an external module, should be referenced within TypeScript by the name specified within the redux definition file.

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } = require("redux");

//... now we can use the imported external module
const myApp = combineReducers({
    SelectedAnswers: selectedAnswers
});

var store = createStore(myApp);
```

You also have to ensure that you have the typings for your external modules, I didn't have this, so this was causing my TypeScript file to fail compilation with an error `Cannot find module 'redux'`.  So I got the typings by installing the definitely typed definition and this allowed the TypeScript file to compile:

> Install-Package react-redux.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

It seems that this is generally available for most external modules that you might want to import, but if they're not you can specify your own definition (put it in a *.d.ts file within your solution), which will allow you TypeScript file to complile:

```
// This can be redux, or any other module that you'd like to use in require() to enable it to compile your TypeScript code
declare module "redux" {
    var _temp: any;
    export = _temp;
}
```

Naturally you won't get the intellisense if you do this, so TypeScript typings are preferred.

When it comes to setting the properties of you `require.config()`, which is called as the entry point to your application, you should:

- Specify your external module locations relative to your `baseUrl`
- Specify your internal modules to be resolved as relative locations

Here's an example of the entry point for my example (**main.ts**, compiles to main.js for use later):

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/", // The base url
    paths: {
        // Named external module (redux in this case)
        "redux": "../node_modules/redux/dist/redux"
    }
});

// Bootstrap the entry point module, notice that this is an 'internal module', hence the relative location being used as the module name
require(["Scripts/myscript"], () => {
    console.log("Your internal module has been resolved and should be running now!")
});
```

This can be called from within your application's page, like so:

```
<script "/node_modules/requirejs/require.js" data-main="scripts/main.js"></script>
```